# BottomSheet - why FAB button over the View? how to Hide the BottoSheet when I focus again on the Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet

I have two problems. My idea was :

When I click on a marker of a googlemap, a bottomsheet shows the details of the marker.

I have two problems right now.

1. when a click on a marker, the bottomsheet view slid up and cover half of te screen (as I wanted) covering the map but the 2 FAB buttons remain still over the bottomsheet (I want them below the bottomSheet).
2. When the bottomSheet is showed, I would like that if I click on the map, the bottomSheet should disappear (it doesn't).

this is my code :

**main_layout_activity.xml**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ankic.it.nasone.NasoneActivity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="normal"

        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/floatingButton"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        />


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a test dialog fragment"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/immagine_lista"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**MyActivity.java**

here the snippets:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    protected FloatingActionButton floatingButton;
    private FloatingActionButton fabAdd;
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;

    ............



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ........

        this.floatingButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
        this.fabAdd=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        this.cl=(CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayoutNasoni) ;


        View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 2):

you have to go to your mainactivity.java class and add this to your onmarkerclick method. it sets the behaviour of the floating action button for the different states of the bottomsheet and remember to do it for both floating action buttons ..its implemented for one of them here `

```
     // set callback for changes
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                // this part hides the button immediately and waits bottom sheet
                // to collapse to show
                if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED== newState) {
                    floatingButton.animate().scaleX(0).scaleY(0).setDuration(0).start();
                    floatingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED == newState) {
                    floatingButton.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(0).start();
                    floatingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN == newState) {
                    floatingButton.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(0).start();
                    floatingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
//        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), marker.getTitle());
        return true;
    }
```